# Upgrade Specialized Tarmac Pro SL3 with SRAM Force AXS

Tags: groupsets

Is it possible to upgrade Specialized Tarmac Pro SL3 with the new SRAM Force AXS group set?

Comment: If it's [this bike](https://www.specialized.com/us/en/tarmac-sl3-pro-sram/p/23506) no, as AXS is hydraulic disc brake only

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus That's probably the answer.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Am I missing something, or do the AXS groupsets also have a rim brake option? https://www.coloradocyclist.com/sram-force-22-groupset

Comment: @WeiwenNg You are right, I retract my previous comment. I was initially looking [here](https://www.sram.com/en/sram/road/series/sram-force-etap-axs) where rim brakes are not mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing a Tarmac Pro SL3 is a slightly older bike, Google search suggest a 2011 model. There's a [Specialized web site page](https://www.specialized.com/us/en/tarmac-sl3-pro-sram/p/23506) but it does not give a model year.

Rim brake versions are offered. Front derailleur comes in braze on and clamp on. Etap is wireless so there are zero cable routing issues. The AXS groups use SRAM DUB bottom brackets which have wide frame compatibility.

The problem comes with the rear hub I think. The bike referenced above is 10 speed so I'm guessing it has a 130mm rear spacing and a 10 speed Hyperglide type freehub body. AXS is 12 speed and uses a XDR cassette driver body. From [SRAM's page on XD and XDR](https://www.sram.com/en/service/articles/sram-xd-and-xdr-driver-body-explained) 'XDR maintains the same hub spacing and flange locations used for 11-speed road compatible HyperGlide freehub bodies'. I'm fairly sure a wheel with a 10 speed Hyperglide freehub body will not be XDR compatible.

Comment: All true. However, rim brake wheels with XDR compatible hubs are available. I'm linking to one good value wheelset by Boyd cycling - disclosure, I have a set of their rims built to White Industries hubs. Dave could take the opportunity to upgrade the wheels also, perhaps. https://boydcycling.com/collections/alloy/products/altamont-alloy-rear-wheel?variant=15361533542449

Comment: @WeiwenNg. yes, replacing the rear hub/wheel is an option or course, although 130mm rather than 135mm rear spacing may be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Instead of upgrading I went with the 2020 Tarmac Pro that comes with this group set.